# Customizing magento emails design with paypal express?

Tags: email, magento, templates, paypal

I already know where to find the email templates to change the email design, but the box with the payment method looks default when it comes to font sizes and colours and this is because i need to locate the file it comes from and add my styling there, as i did with the rest of the files (items.php and the rest in /templates/email).

The payment solution is paypal express checkout and i cannot find where the template is stored?

Can someone help me locate it (if a file) or how to style it if dynamic?

The table in the "parent" email template files already have the right css code in the table structure (such as font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px etc) but for some reason this part of the email does not inherit those?

Thanks